# Prototype Ajax.Request not working in google chrome browser version 14.0.835.163 onwards

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, prototypejs, ajax.request

I have been using prototype's Ajax.Request for making ajax calls.

With the new versions of google chrome browser,this call seems to be breaking.

The onLoading function of Ajax.Request seems to be triggering 
after onSuccess and also the overall request processing is not happening as expected.

This happened to be from the version 14.0.835.163 of the chrome browser.
Prior to this version, it was working normally.

Has anybody experienced such an issue.

Comment: can you post your code please, there might be an issue there

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's fast iteration of versions makes it prone to releasing bugs more often that other browsers.  I would suggest writing up a test page and submitting a bug to them here before it makes it to production:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

There is also a newer version out as we speak:  14.0.835.202 (Official Build 103287) Try updating to that version and see if the problem persists. Lastly, try switching to the beta channel and see if the problem persists there.

http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/